# strong name for a dll in .net

Tags: c#, .net

Dll is said to be have strong name, if it has

1. Assembly name without extension
2. Version
3. culture
4. Public key

A strong name shall be provided for a dll. I found that either `csc.exe`(in case of C#) and `al.exe` can use used to provide the strong name to the dll. When I have to use `csc.exe` and `al.exe` to provide the strong name for the dll?

What are the uses of `al.exe` apart from signing the dll?

Apart from signing a dll, al.exe also used to create publisher policy assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) is csharpcompiler.

[al.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is assembly linker.

The links explains what they perform and that would give you an idea of when to use either or what each executable performs.

Answer (score 1):

it's [Assembly Linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

It generates a file with an assembly manifest from one or more files that are either modules or resource files

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a strong name, you must signed your dll using a snk file. You can for example do it via [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms247123.aspx) or via [msbuild](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/26/474079.aspx) .